# socket programming in windows to send data freezes for sometime and getting delayed for sometime?

Tags: c++

I am able to send data successfully with a static class through socket programming, it works fine for small amount of data but in production environment it is freezing for sometime and again it is starting to send data, i am unable to figure out what is the problem? can you please help. Code is as below.

```
            DWORD BytesCount;  
    WSABUF Buffer[1];
    DWORD Flag = 0;

    Buffer[0].len = SendLength;
    Buffer[0].buf = SendData;
    if (WSASend(*socket, Buffer, 1, &BytesCount, Flag, NULL, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (BytesCount != SendLength )
            Result = -2;
        else
        {
            if (ReturnAnswer)
            {
                int Res = 0, recBufStart;
                DWORD RecvCount = 0, AllRecv = 0;

                Buffer[0].len = ReceiveLength;
                Buffer[0].buf = ReceiveData;
                recBufStart = 0;
                saAction = saReceive;

                // We need to Receive until we get all the data. When WSARecv call might only return zero bytes
                bool Stop = true; // true as we dont need to recieve anything from the server.
                while (!Stop)
                {
                    Res = WSARecv(*socket, &Buffer[recBufStart], (recBufStart == 0 ? 1 : 0), &RecvCount, &Flag, NULL, NULL);
                    if (Res == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        Stop = true;
                    else
                    {
                        AllRecv = AllRecv + RecvCount;
                        if (AllRecv == ReceiveLength || RecvCount == 0)
                            Stop = true;    // Stop
                        else
                        {
                            Buffer[0].buf = &ReceiveData[AllRecv];
                            Buffer[0].len = ReceiveLength - (AllRecv);
                            recBufStart = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (Res == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Result = WSAGetLastError();                 
            }
        }
    }
    else
        Result = WSAGetLastError();
```

Comment: Is it freezing in `WSASend` or `WSARecv`?

Comment: i am using WSASend , as for time being i am not receiving anything as you can see the boolean is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this may be the problem but from the Microsoft documentation for WSASend there is the following:

> When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as WSASend with the lpOverlapped parameter set to NULL, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete.

Also, your receive code seems rather complicated. In what case would recBufStart be anything other than 0? I also would not use the variable "Stop". Just issue a break statement to exit the while loop.

EDIT: Looking at your receive code a little more closely, you set Stop to true prior to the while (!Stop) i.e., while (Stop == false). So it won't get to WSARecv. Is this intentional? If it is, the the Microsoft explanation and the answer below mine seem to indicate your issue i.e. you are continually sending and Winsock is having to wait before it can send more data.

Comment: ok, intentionally i am not receiving any data now and problem what you are saying seems correct , so what has to be done to avoid this? I am using select while creating socket and getting in between timed out error.

Comment: I've not really seen code that just sends data and not receives. I would think that t some point you need to get something back from the peer you are sending to and at that point you'll probably get the network event that unblocks WSASend. Just to test simply do a WSASend followed by a WSARecv. It may be easier for you to use the Berkeley sockets interface rather than the Microsoft interface to avoid all this overlapped I/O stuff i.e. send and not WSASend, socket and not WSASocket and recv rather than WSARecv.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WSASend and WSARecv is blocking mode (two last parameters are NULL). This means that as soon as you filled up the TCP/IP stack buffers the next call to WSASend will block until there is again space in the buffer (i.e. data has been sent out).

You better make use of asynchronous calls and [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am using this and getting timed out , is this causing a problem. code is as below.if (select(0, NULL, &ConnectSockets, NULL, &Timeout) == SOCKET_ERROR)
 {
  LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T("Primary server connection failed - a select call with error %ld"),  WSAGetLastError());
  Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  if (ConnectSockets.fd_count == 0)
  {
   LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed -  timedout to connect..."));
   Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
   return false;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

TCP stack may block an application, if the application sends a data block that is bigger than the send buffer size of the socket.

Try to increase `SO_SNDBUF` option of your socket. If you want to avoid blocking, it shold be bigger than bigest `SendLength` value.
Use `setsockopt()` function for changing value of SO_SNDBUF.